# More detailed explanation about GetPostBackEventReference method

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

I understand that this will causes a page reload (partial or full, depending on how your UpdatePanels are set up)

But,

1. where in the code I should put it (client or server side)?
2. which control should I send to the method? Is it must be inside the `UpdatePanel`?
3. does this method work only for controls inside update panels?
4. must the control have a postback capability?
5. what is the engine behind this? How does this method work, so I could use it properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The function call returns a string of executable JavaScript, which you need to write to the client somewhere in your response.
2. Typically, you're sending your Page (this/Me) unless you have a control that you specifically want to handle the postback (ie, that implements IPostBackEventHandler)
3. GetPostBackEventReference is not related to UpdatePanels; if you have one, it will handle the postback.
4. No (see #2)
5. This makes a postback to the page. If you want it to raise an event when it posts back, you need to implement IPostBackEventHandler, either on your page or on one of your controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153112.aspx

Comment: thanks, but all of this i knew, i asked for more deep understanding. the scenario i faced was when i used this method to indicate that a PostBack came from specific UpdatePanel while clicking a td in the UpdatePanel, and the EventTarget didn't changed even when PostBack from other UpdatePanels.

Comment: Why do you need to get down to the level of EventTarget? Pass in the name of the containing UpdatePanel as the postback argument, if you like.